# Can anyone recommend best practices for profiling Ruby on Rails software under Passenger/nginx combination in a live server environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, amazon-ec2, profiling, profiler

I am attempting to determine what can possibly be the causative factor for 20+ second response times from a Rails 3 application located in EC2 using Elasticache.  I have reason to believe the problem is in fact cache related, but I have no numbers to prove it.  I'd like to get those numbers.  For the sake of completeness, we're running the applications atop Ubuntu 12.04 .

Searching Google, I found nothing directly relevant to my situation, and no StackOverflow topics I could find were even remotely relevant to my situation.  If anyone can point me to some documentation on the matter, I'd be quite appreciative.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best tool for this to be New Relic.

http://newrelic.com/

I don't work for them and get no benefit from you trying them.

They have a free level that you can start with. If you go up to the non-free version you can literally trace all your requests through different models and into the database telling you how long the app spent in each section. It's a great tool for profiling.

Comment: Hi Kevin.  Alas, this specific portion of our Rails application doesn't employ many models or any databases; it does make extensive back-end API calls though.  Can it also be used to isolate long-running method invokations or RPC calls?  (While I'm waiting for your response, I'll review the NewRelic website.  Thanks for the tip!)

Comment: NR does have support for background processing (example DelayedJob), in addition, it will show you performance of connections to external services - hard to really say without understanding more about your app.

Comment: I'd try it first. It's pretty easy to setup and even the free version has value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you, by any chance have access to standard web logs including URLs and response times?

I faced a similar situation, searched the web, found nothing relevant, and eventually decided to roll my own, which I shared in this SO post:

[Profiling a multi-tiered, distributed, web application (server side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178903/profiling-a-multi-tiered-distributed-web-application-server-side)

While it is far from perfect and may be too high level for some use-cases, it gave me a pretty quick and broad insight into where the application I was trying to profile is spending most of its time in, and what the slowest parts are.  HTH.

The best parts of it are that:

- It is 100% platform and programming language independent.
- It is a 100% free software solution

Comment: Alas, I no longer work at the organization where this problem is relevant, but thanks for contributing.  I hope others who suffer my former fate can find this useful.